# Joining keys/values as array of hashes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

The following code:

```
product.css('.simImage').each do | product |
  product_image_url = product.xpath('.//a/img/@src').to_s
  product_hash[:product_image_url] ||= []
  product_hash[:product_image_url] << { :image_url => product_image_url }
end
```

produces something like this:

> [{:image_url=>"41g2nv06iwl._sl500_ss120_.jpg"},
>   {:image_url=>"511vczsu4pl._sl500_ss120_.jpg"}, etc., etc.]

and this code:

```
product.css('.simProductInfo').each do | product |
  product_asin = product.xpath('.//a/@href').first.value[/(?<=\/)[A-Z\d]{5,}/]
  product_hash[:product_asin] ||= []
  product_hash[:product_asin] << { :asin => product_asin }
end
```

produces something like this:

> [{:asin=>"0744014476", }, {:asin=>"B000ZKA0J6"}, etc., etc.]

I have many of methods like this. But they all scrap the elements of a product and place them in different hashes/symbols. How can I do it so that I can join them to produce something like this?

> [{:asin=>"0744014476", :image_url=>"41g2nv06iwl._sl500_ss120_.jpg", etc.}, {:asin=>"B000ZKA0J6", :image_url=>"511vczsu4pl._sl500_ss120_.jpg", etc.}, etc., etc.]

and store that array of hashes in `product_hash[:product]`?

Comment: give the relevant HTML too.. please.. Without looking the same probably can't give you good suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
product_hash[:product_image_url].zip(product_hash[:product_asin]).map {|arr| arr[0].merge(arr[1]) }
```

If you have more arrays, say `a1, a2, a3`, then you could do

```
a1.zip(a2, a3).map {|arr| arr.reduce :merge }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way how can I do it if I want to add more arrays in the future? More than one?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly.